# Force Knockout component in Durandal page to wait for Ajax call before binding

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, durandal

I am trying to bind my parameter of a custom knockout component into the viewmodel with a value provided by an ajax call.  However it appears the binding is taking place before the ajax call completes.  Is there anyway to make sure the ajax call completes before the binding occurs? Thanks.

The view with the custom component is something like this

```
<section>
    <mycustomcomponent params="item: item"> </mycustomcomponent>
</section>
```

Here are the relevant parts of the viewmodel

```
define(function (require) {
    var Item = require('models/item');

    var item;

    return {
        activate: function () {
            var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'myapicall',
                success: function (data) {
                    item = new Item(data);
                }
            });
            return ajaxCall;
        },


        item: item,
    };
});
```

Comment: try `var ajaxCall = return $.ajax.....`, this should prevent calling the `attached` handler to get called synchronously...

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the component in an `if` binding so that it doesn't render until `item` contains something valid.

```
<section data-bind="if: item">
    <mycustomcomponent params="item: item"> </mycustomcomponent>
</section>
```